# Cycle sort Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, cycle-sort

I was browsing through the internet when i found out that there is an algorithm called cycle sort which makes the least number of memory writes.But i am not able to find the algorithm anywhere.How to detect whether a cycle is there or not in an array?
Can anybody give a complete explanation for this algorithm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimizing a cycle sort implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856635/optimizing-a-cycle-sort-implementation)

Comment: The term cycle means cycle notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_notation

Comment: as i went through the post Optimizing a cycle sort implementation i felt its same as selection sort i.e tryin to find the minimum position through many iterations.In wat way is cycle sort different from selection sort?Is it because this algorithm doesn swap numbers if it is already in its correct position or is there any other reason?

Comment: It wud be really helpful if u post in an example demonstrating cycle sort.

Comment: can anybody tel me the algorithm for this pls?

Comment: @gogo you sure you did not find it here :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort

Answer (score 20):

The cycle sort algorithm is motivated by something called a *[cycle decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation)*. Cycle decompositions are best explained by example. Let's suppose that you have this array:

```
4 3 0 1 2
```

Let's imagine that we have this sequence in sorted order, as shown here:

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

How would we have to shuffle this sorted array to get to the shuffled version? Well, let's place them side-by-side:

```
0 1 2 3 4
4 3 0 1 2
```

Let's start from the beginning. Notice that the number 0 got swapped to the position initially held by 2. The number 2, in turn, got swapped to the position initially held by 4. Finally, 4 got swapped to the position initially held by 0. In other words, the elements 0, 2, and 4 all were cycled forward one position. That leaves behind the numbers 1 and 3. Notice that 1 swaps to where 3 is and 3 swaps to where 1 is. In other words, the elements 1 and 3 were cycled forward one position.

As a result of the above observations, we'd say that the sequence 4 3 0 1 2 has cycle decomposition (0 2 4)(1 3). Here, each group of terms in parentheses means "circularly cycle these elements forward." This means to cycle 0 to the spot where 2 is, 2 to the spot where 4 is, and 4 to the spot where 0 was, then to cycle 1 to the spot where 3 was and 3 to the spot where 1 is.

If you have the cycle decomposition for a particular array, you can get it back in sorted order making the fewest number of writes by just cycling everything backward one spot. The idea behind [cycle sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort) is to try to determine what the cycle decomposition of the input array is, then to reverse it to put everything back in its place.

Part of the challenge of this is figuring out where everything initially belongs since a cycle decomposition assumes you know this. Typically, cycle sort works by going to each element and counting up how many elements are smaller than it. This is expensive - it contributes to the Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) runtime of the sorting algorithm - but doesn't require any writes.

Comment: i was reading this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/which-sorting-algorithm-makes-minimum-number-of-writes/ 
for input `1,7,2,3,5,4,6`
1st step 
1,7,2,3,5,4,7 temp:6 (1 write)
but ain't it 2 writes (replacing 6 by 7 and writing 6 in temp) ?
or temp write ain't counted ?

BTW nice and clear explanation

Comment: The writes counted are the writes to the array, since the assumption is that it might be in flash, which degrades over time with writes. Writes to variables in memory are presumed to be free since RAM is fast and doesn't usually degrade.

Answer (score 0):

here's a python implementation if anyone needs

```
def cycleSort(vector):
    writes = 0

    # Loop through the vector to find cycles to rotate.
    for cycleStart, item in enumerate(vector):

        # Find where to put the item.
        pos = cycleStart
        for item2 in vector[cycleStart + 1:]:
            if item2 < item:
                pos += 1

        # If the item is already there, this is not a cycle.
        if pos == cycleStart:
            continue

        # Otherwise, put the item there or right after any duplicates.
        while item == vector[pos]:
            pos += 1
        vector[pos], item = item, vector[pos]
        writes += 1

        # Rotate the rest of the cycle.
        while pos != cycleStart:

            # Find where to put the item.
            pos = cycleStart
            for item2 in vector[cycleStart + 1:]:
                if item2 < item:
                    pos += 1

            # Put the item there or right after any duplicates.
            while item == vector[pos]:
                pos += 1
            vector[pos], item = item, vector[pos]
            writes += 1

    return writes


x = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 9, 3.5, 5, 8, 4, 7, 0, 6]
w = cycleSort(x) 
print w, x
```